# ZXing library tutorial

Tags: qr-code, zxing

I have read about Zxing library and I have also searched information in the home page of the project (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) but I need a good tutorial to learn how to develop applications using this library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/zxing-1-7-for-android-on-eclipse/

... but you haven't really said what you are trying to do, and what you've tried, what didn't work, and so what your specific question is.

Comment: i think the link provided is not the one you intended, right?